# How to extract duplicate numbers from a log file?

Tags: linux, shell

I have some log files in one of my server having the below mentioned log entries.

FTM.FC103.20181228034503.20181228035250:2018-12-28 08:19:59.893 FAIL DROP: Too many resend tries failed Failed for request id: 8397796 Cause: unknown Info:  Code: ,USSD RequestId=8397796 OriginalId=8397545 EventCorrelationI
d="03a4264124" CreationTime="20181228081949" ResendCount=1 Timestamp=1545968994377 (Fri Dec 28 08:19:54 AFT 2018) State=STATE_SENT **SubscriberNumber=96700606310** UssdText=Last event was charged 3.00 RYL, Duration 0:00:52, Remaining balance
 35.29 AFN and will expire 25.12.2020.1500 RYL = 32GB valid 30 Days, Dial *811*32*1#. NumberingPlan=1 Nadi=4 UssdFormat=2

I wanted to extract the following information from these logs:

1- Extract all SubscriberNumber from the log files.

2- Then find the SubscriberNumbers which have multiple occurrences in the logs.

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
grep -oP 'SubscriberNumber=\K(\d+)' logfile | sort -n | uniq -cd
```

- **grep -oP 'SubscriberNumber=\K(\d+)' logfile** isolates all individual SubscriberNumbers from your `logfile`;
- **sort -n** sorts them numerically, and
- **uniq -cd** prints any duplicate numbers, i.e. those with multiple occurrences, including a count.

Comment: Many Thanks dear Ozzy, can you plz also help in counting the duplicate occurrences of each number?

for example:

11 ---- 967090099887

Comment: Thanks again dear Ozzy. I have got the duplicate occurrences.
now is it possible if I can get the list of those numbers having maximum duplicate occurrences for example between 20 - 100 or let say more than 30?

grep -oP 'SubscriberNumber=\K(\d+)' 30.unknown.txt | sort -n | uniq -cd
      3 96700000165
      2 96700000584
     23 96700001632
      6 96700001744
      4 96700001876
      2 96700002632
      2 96700003071
      2 96700004656
      3 96700004948
     10 96700006053
      2 96700007154
      2 96700007248

Comment: @JackAnderson It would be easier to help you if you'd first formulate a _complete_ question. Alternatively, you can mark the original question as answered and open a new one. Answering an iteratively changing question may require repeated revisions of the answer, and even backtracking on a chosen approach.

Comment: Dear Ozzy, can you please also explain the purpose of following switches?

\K(\d+

Comment: @JackAnderson The \d matches any digit; (\d+) is a group of one or more consecutive digits. The \K is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33573920/what-does-k-mean-in-this-regex.

Comment: @JackAnderson Now that I am reconsidering the answer: the regex should also work without the grouping parentheses (, ). That may simplify the regex and ease your understanding.